# System.NullReferenceException: When adding item to a list

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I am having an issue when trying to add an item to a list. I see many questions but I still don't get it in my case. 
This is my definition :

```
public class DBStatus
    {
        [DataMember]
        public DBOperation Type { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<DBMessageType> Message { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<string> InnerException { get; set; }
    }
```

I declared this class and trying to add an item.

```
private void button19_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBStatus dbstst = new DBStatus();
        dbstst.Message.Add(DBMessageType.INVALID_OR_EXPIRED_FUNCTION_REQUEST);
        dbstst.InnerException.Add("testing code");

        int k = 0;
    }
```

I get System.NullReferenceException when adding the items.

Error message: "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

I know my last two list items are null post declaration, why can not I add ?

Any help is appreciated.

thanks,
PG

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A List is null by default and you need to initialize the list before adding elements into it

**Option 1 :**

```
private void button19_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBStatus dbstst = new DBStatus();

        dbstst.Message = new List<DBMessageType>();
        dbstst.Message.Add(DBMessageType.INVALID_OR_EXPIRED_FUNCTION_REQUEST);

        dbstst.InnerException = new List<string>();
        dbstst.InnerException.Add("testing code");

        int k = 0;
    }
```

**Option 2 :** 
You can also do this via class constructor :

```
public class DBStatus
    {
        [DataMember]
        public DBOperation Type { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<DBMessageType> Message { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<string> InnerException { get; set; }

        public DBStatus(){ //initialize here
          Message = new List<DBMessageType>();
          InnerException = new List<string>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Option 2 saved a lot of time as I only have to change constructor.